# Can I use Nodejs cluster for parallel execution of a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

Actually I want a parallel implementation of request method using Nodejs Cluster or any other way. I want to use cluster for a script for parallel execution, not for app server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, but if you want several functions to be executed at the same time, make them async

```
async function foo(a, b){
   /* do something */
}
```

And then just call them like normal functions

```
foo("a", "b");
foo(1, 2);
```

and so on, they will be executed parallel

Answer (score 0):

The best method will be using the child process in nodejs, this will be executed as a new process. The method that needs to be executed should be in a separate file and on executing the file that should run the function.

```
    let childProcess = require('child_process'); let os  = require('os');

    let cpuCount = os.cpus().length;

    for(let i=0;i<cpuCount;i++)
   { 
      var child = child_process.fork('./yourMethod.js'); 
    }
```

check https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html for detailed info